# using Moq and NUnit , what is write approach / better syntax?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, installation, moq

I am trying to test this behavior

--  BLOGTableAdapter.GetBlogsByTitle(string
   title) is called and for once only

-- and is called with string having
   length greater than 1,

-- and it returns BLOGDataTable Object

```
 [Test]
    public void GetBlogsByBlogTitleTest4()
    {
        var mockAdapter = new Mock<BLOGTableAdapter>();
        var mockTable = new Mock<BLOGDataTable>();

        mockAdapter.Setup(x => x.GetBlogsByTitle(It.Is<string>(s => s.Length > 0))).Returns(mockTable.Object);

        var blogBl = new BlogManagerBLL(mockAdapter.Object);
        blogBl.GetBlogsByBlogTitle("Thanks for reading my question");

        mockAdapter.VerifyAll();
        mockAdapter.Verify(x => x.GetBlogsByTitle(It.Is<string>(s => s.Length > 0)), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
```

When a calls is made to GetBlogsByTitle(string title), in class say "BlogManagerBLL" in Data Aceess Layer

```
public BLOGDataTable GetBlogsByBlogTitle(string title)
        {
            return Adapter.GetBlogsByTitle(title);
        }
```

As you can see, I am using two seperate statements to get these checks done

```
mockAdapter.Setup(x => x.GetBlogsByTitle(It.Is<string>(s => s.Length > 0))).Returns(mockTable.Object);    
mockAdapter.Verify(x => x.GetBlogsByTitle(It.Is<string>(s => s.Length > 0)), Times.Exactly(1));
```

1. How can I put this into one
   statement ?
2. **Am I testing right things ?**

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to put it in one statement?  It is clearer using two.

Comment: Because, for the sake of one check, that this method is called once,
I have to write second statement. I cannot find any way to get this checked in first one.

Comment: cannot put "Times.Exactly(1)" or similar check in first statement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're testing two things, you should write two tests.

```
[Test]
public void BlogTableAdapter_should_be_called_with_string_having_length_greater_than_1()
{
    var mockAdapter = new Mock<BLOGTableAdapter>();

    var blogBl = new BlogManagerBLL(mockAdapter.Object);
    blogBl.GetBlogsByBlogTitle("Thanks for reading my question");

    mockAdapter.Verify(x => x.GetBlogsByTitle(It.Is<string>(s => s.Length > 0)));
}
```

and

```
[Test]
public void BlogTableAdapter_should_return_a_BLOGDataTable_object()
{
    var mockAdapter = new Mock<BLOGTableAdapter>();
    mockAdapter.Setup(x => x.GetBlogsByTitle(It.Is<string>(s => s.Length > 0))).Returns(new BLOGDataTable());

    var blogBl = new BlogManagerBLL(mockAdapter.Object);
    var returnValue = blogBl.GetBlogsByBlogTitle("Thanks for reading my question");

    Assert.That(returnValue, Is.TypeOf(typeof(BLOGDataTable)));
}
```

So I guess my advice is don't put them together, create a test for each. And I'd say you're testing the right things.

Comment: just another point: I though we should use one [Test] method for corresponding method in our code class ? you are suggesting a test method for every check for the corresponding method ?

say I have 3 methods in a class and want to check 4 things each, there are going to be 12 [Test] methods ? write ?

should a write separate [TestFixture] for each method ?

Comment: @Asad: Chris is right, I've never heard the bit about one test method per method. One assert per test is more standard. [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/) has good guidance on this.